# How to remove motherboard drivers?

Tags: drivers, uninstall

I've recentely reinstalled Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, and installed my motherboard's chipset drivers with it. (which wasn't on my older installation)

Now, I am having issues with getting BSoDs that say "A clock interrupt was not received on a secondary processor within the allocated time interval", and I've seen that this may be caused by an incorrent Vcore of the CPU. The problem is, I haven't overclocked my CPU at all.

I've heard I can fix it by removing any software that handles power consumption, which to my understanding, includes the chipset drivers.

I'd like to know how I can remove those drivers.

System:

```
Intel Core i5-750 @ Default 2.66 GHz
4GB DDR3-1333 MHz RAM
AMD HD Radeon 5770 1GB
Gigabyte P55M-UD2 rev1.1 motherboard
CoolerMaster Real Power M520 (520watt)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if needed, uninstall the driver package from the `Programs and Features` control panel. They may or may not be there. But if they are, make sure you uninstall them.

Then, roll back the drivers associated with the devices. From the Device Manager, right-click the device whose drivers you want to roll back. Select `Properties`, then `Driver`. Then select `Roll Back Driver`.

Comment: Which one do I need to select? http://i.imgur.com/BCRYA.png (There's no rollback option btw, only uninstall (rollback not available; no updates, I just installed the latest update straight from the Gigabyte site)

Comment: Check them all to see which have Intel drivers. If they have no rollback option, then the driver package didn't change their driver.